# I am trying to pass an .osm file into a python function but getting NameError

Tags: python-2.7, openstreetmap

Here is my code :-

```html
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
filename= "kolkata_india.osm"

def count_tags(filename):
    tags = {}
    for event, elem in ET.iterparse(filename):
        if elem.tag in tags:
            tags[elem.tag] += 1
        else:
            tags[elem.tag] = 1

    print tags
if __name__ == "__main__":
 count_tags(filename)
```

and here is the error message :-

```html
C:\Python27\Udacity\mongodb>python mapparser.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mapparser.py", line 17, in <module>
    count_tags(filename)
  File "mapparser.py", line 8, in count_tags
    filename = kolkata_india.osm
NameError: global name 'kolkata_india' is not defined
```

What is it here that I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Try putting quotes around 'kolkata_india.osm', that way it will be a string instead of a reference to the non existing object kolkata_india.

Comment: Still not working after placing the quotes.